# How to replace part of string with another in js?

Tags: javascript, xml, string

I'm using js to read an xml file elements and replace some nodes name with another by replacing part of the string, but when running my app nothing happening, that's my code:

```
$('#dummy').load('cafe.xml',function() {
initialize();
})
function initialize(){
ct=$('menu').children().length;
for(cati==0;cati<=ct-1;cati++)
{
cats[cati]=$('menu').children().eq(cati).prop('nodeName');

// modifing the whitespaces and special characters
var realname = cats[cati];
if(realname.indexOf(".") != -1){
    realname.replace(/\./g,' ');
    }
if(realname.indexOf("1") != -1){
    realname.replace(/\1/g,'\'');
    }

if(realname.indexOf("2") != -1){
    realname.replace(/\2/g,'&');
    }

    if(realname.indexOf(":") != -1){
    realname.replace(/\:/g,'(');
    }

if(realname.indexOf("!") != -1){
    realname.replace(/\!/g,')');
    }

    if(realname.indexOf("0") != -1){
    realname.replace(/\0/g,'/');
    } 
}
```

Comment: You have more `{` than `}`. There must be a JS/parse error. Check it.

Comment: Don't forget to use `var` to declare local variables in your functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` doesn't change the original string. Try with something like

```
realname = realname.replace(/.../g, "...");
```

Anyway, I'd ditch all those `if`, that are kind of useless given what you're doing.

Comment: but what about the if thing ?

Comment: @MRefaat That's because you're checking if the string contains a character, but if it doesn't `replace` won't change anything anyway. If you remove the `if` statements, you can chain all those methods: `realname = realname.replace(/\./g, " ").replace(/1/g, "'").replace(...)...`.